# C# Add DBContext as generic type parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

In the following class, how can I add the DBContext as a generic type parameter:

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private MyDBContext dataContext;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> dbset;

    protected Repository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
    {
        DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
        dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
    }

    protected IDatabaseFactory DatabaseFactory
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    protected MyDBContext DataContext
    {
        get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = DatabaseFactory.Get()); }
    }

    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        dbset.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        dbset.Attach(entity);
        dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        dbset.Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

Something in the lines of:

```
public abstract class Repository<C, T> : IRepository<T> where T
```

Would it work and how would the implementation be?

Comment: You already use `T` for entity, you are not constrained to the letter T, you can name them like `TEntity` and `TDataContext`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
public abstract class Repository<TContext, TEntity> : IRepository<TContext, TSet>
    where TContext : DbContext
    where TEntity : class
{
    private TContext context;
    private readonly IDbSet<TEntity>;

    // ...
}
```

Basically just replace every reference to `MyDBContext` with `TContext`.

Comment: I tried to do that before, but I get an error on the line: 'get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = DatabaseFactory.Get()); }'

Comment: That's presumably because DatabaseFactory.Get() is returning something that can't be assigned to a DbContext variable.